# How to expand/be-limited-to a fixed parent container height, child parent container?

Tags: css

I have many parent containers. There are many instances of this on a page.
They have different heights.

This is the hierarchy of DIVs:

```
.parent_container
  |-----> .title
  |-----> .content
```

`.parent_container` has a fix height and `.title` takes up some of the height
I want `.content` to take up the rest of the height, but not occupied by `.title`.

How would I go about doing this?

Currently I have this, but because the parent containers are different heights, the 90% doesn't always work well because the `.title` is always a certain height specified by a `H2` style.

Is there a way in CSS to say "content `height = parent_height` - title height"?

```
/*just an example...different parent_containers have diff heights)*/
    .parent_container{
    height:530px;
    }

    .content {
    height:90%; /* to make room for title */
    overflow:auto; /*show scrollbars*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, in this case, to make it work, but you'll have to adjust HTML and CSS.

The HTML change:

```
.parent_container
|-----> .content
   |-----> .title
   |-----> .scroll_container
```

The title goes inside the content.  You may need to override some styles in .title if .content affects them.

Then, set height of .content to 100%.  Now you may have to adjust the CSS on .title and .content to make it work, depending on styling, but it should be doable.  Put `overflow: auto` on .content_scroller and you'll want to remove this same style from the .content container.  .content_scroller can then scroll content as needed, and the .content container can be 100% of the height of the .parent_container.

Comment: That didn't work for me. For some reason my .scroll_container content is going beyond the bounds of .parent_container.

This is essentially what I have as my CSS.

.parent_container{ height:500px; }
.content { height:100%; /*100% of parent*/ }
.scroll_container { overflow:auto; }

(sorry...I don't know how to format comments)

Answer (score 0):

there is no current way of calculating with css, although calc() is on the works.  there is a big argument saying that doing calculations in css is s parfomance nightmare though. but that's off topic.

one quick fix would be to put .title **inside** .content, and giving the content a 100% height. saving you the need to calculate anything.

option two is to calculate this using javascript.

Comment: I think I may go back to my fixed calculation and set a specific % that .scrolling_content will occupy of its container.